# How to submit/update form without submit click in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

generated a `recruitment` model that has `one_to_many` association with `attendance` model. now i want to submit/update form whenever user changes attendance dropdown. here is my code-

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

        <% (1..(Time.days_in_month Time.now.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
              <th><%= date %></th>
        <% end %>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @recruitment.each do |recruitment| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= recruitment.name %></td>

            <% (1..(Time.days_in_month Time.now.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
                  <td>


                    <%= form_for Attendance.new do |f| %>
                        <div>
                          <div class="wrapper-class">
                              <%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['H', 3]]%>
                          </div>

                          <div>
                            <%= f.hidden_field :attendance_date, value: (Time.now.strftime("%Y").to_s+"-"+Time.now.strftime("%m").to_s+"-"+date.to_s)%>
                          </div>

                            <%=f.hidden_field :recruitment_id, value: recruitment.id%>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small float-right' %>
                          </div>

                    <% end %>
                  </td>
            <% end %>
```

i dont want to click `submit` on every time i change input select.

i tried this-

```
  <%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['H', 3]], :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Are you using rails-ujs? If that's the case you can add something like this onchange: "Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit');".

Comment: @Smek yes it's included.

Comment: Well in that case you should be able to replace this.form.submit() with Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit') in your onchange attribute. It will fire the same form event Rails does when submitting a form via rails-ujs.

Comment: @Smek i tried as i post along with code but it did not worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect if you inspect the HTML code this is generating, you won't see an `onchange` attribute for your select field.

Like this
[image]

The `select` method is expecting a hash of `options` before it gets to `html_options`, so to fix this, we do

```
<%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['H', 3]], {}, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
```

If you need to specify any other HTML options such as a class or style, you would do so like this

```
<%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['H', 3]], {}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit()', class: 'some-css-class' } %>
```

Note the curly-brackets around the `onchange` and `class` attributes.

Relevant documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select